# Developing unicode application in android

Tags: android, unicode

I tried to develop application in persian language, as i understood android doesn't support persian and many others by default, i didn't want to install persian fonts, in android and jailbreaking phone for supporting persian,
is there any way for supporting persian in apps without jailbreaking for installing new fonts.
i added fonts to assets directory and load them as `TypeFace` as below

```
TypeFace typeFace =Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

but text appears separately

[image: incorrect text]

and it must display as

[image: correct text]

is there any way for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching i found this solution 
http://code.google.com/p/arabicreshaper/

Answer (score 0):

My only tip is to try another font. Sometimes that might be a font issue. I have used a custom font (latin alphabet) and it didn't have any extra spacing.

Comment: All I can give to you is this: http://goo.gl/JFeAG (be sure to check for proper copyrights)